Multi tag replace between values
I have some script which makes replacements. It works fine, but because of replaced values standing close to each other i've got more than one  between values.
It looks like:
<br />
Value

<br />
Value

<br />


<br />
Value

<br />
Value

<br />


<br />
Value

<br />


<br />

<br />

My task is to get only one <br> between values:
<br />
Value

<br />
Value

<br />
Value

Because of not so many variations in my list I know one decision for all available variants but it is bad hardcode something like:
var mystring=`<br />


<br />`

for (i=0; i<mystring.length; i++){
          var regex = new RegExp(mystring[i],"g");
           mystring = mystring.replace(regex, "");
       }    

Is there any elegant way to solve my case? Thinking of regexp but it's too hard for me to write it. Or may be there is another way?
Full example:




  function textareadValue() {
        var mystring =``;
        mystring = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
        var find1 = ["DEER", "ELK", "PANDA", "THUNDERBIRD", "Text for DELETE 1", "Text for DELETE 3", "Text for DELETE 4", "Text for DELETE 5", "Text for DELETE 6", "Text for DELETE 7", "Text for DELETE 8", "Text for DELETE 9", "Text for DELETE 10"];
        var find2 = /(\d{4})/g;
        var find3 =["REPLACE THIS TEXT 1","REPLACE THIS TEXT 2", "REPLACE THIS TEXT 3", "REPLACE THIS TEXT 4",  "REPLACE THIS TEXT 5"]
        var replace="<br />";
        var replace3 = ["TEXT REPLACED 1","TEXT REPLACED 2", "TEXT REPLACED 3","TEXT REPLACED 4","TEXT REPLACED 5"];
            
        for (i=0; i<find1.length; i++){
          var regex = new RegExp(find1[i],"g");
           mystring = mystring.replace(regex, "");
       }
        for (i=0; i<mystring.length; i++){
            mystring = mystring.replace(find3[i], replace3[i]);
       }
            
        mystring = mystring.replace(find2, replace);
        
        
       
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=mystring;
            
        console.log(mystring);
        } 
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Clear text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
<body>
  <div class="columns mt-0 pt-0 mb-5 is-mobile">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column is-three-quarters mb3">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Enter text here:</label>
    <div class="control">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Text" id="myTextArea">Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 1
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text for DELETE 1
2024
Text for DELETE 2
2024
Text for DELETE 4
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text for DELETE 5
DEER
2024
Text for DELETE 6
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 2
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 3
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 4
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
DEER
Text Value 
Text Value
ELK
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
PANDA
2024
Text for DELETE 7
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text for DELETE 9
PANDA
2024
Text for DELETE 10
2024</textarea><Br>
       <button class="button is-link" onclick="textareadValue();">Clean</button>
    </div>
  </div><br clear="all">
   <div id="result" class="pl-10"></div>
 </div>
<div class="column"></div>
</div>
  </body>




much easier to do with HTML elements than with strings

"but it is bad hardcode something like" - I can't even tell what that would be supposed to achieve. You'd be looping over every character in mystring there, converting it to a regex, and then replacing it with an empty string. Can't see how that is even remotely supposed to make sense (apart from the fact that you are also manipulating the string while you are looping over it, which isn't a good idea to begin with.)



much easier to do with HTML elements than with strings - but how?



@CBroe I understand that my idea is very bad that's why I've created this post asking for help.

mystring = mystring.replace(/<br \/>(\s+<br \/>)+/g, '<br>'); should probably do the job.

@CBroe thanks but actually not.

https://jsfiddle.net/sn3o94pm/ not the desired result then ...?

@CBroe Thanks to be eager to help. I saw your example working but not in my case (i posted full code in the question description).

Seems to me that i find an exit not an optimal as it seems but just working.
I've changed an order of replacement a bit and added one more regexp to clear new line symbols.
Thanks everybody for the help.


function textareadValue() {
        var mystring =``;
        mystring = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
        var find1 = ["DEER", "ELK", "PANDA", "THUNDERBIRD", "Text for DELETE 1", "Text for DELETE 3", "Text for DELETE 4", "Text for DELETE 5", "Text for DELETE 6", "Text for DELETE 7", "Text for DELETE 8", "Text for DELETE 9", "Text for DELETE 10"];
        var find2 = /(\d{4})/g;
        var find3 =["REPLACE THIS TEXT 1","REPLACE THIS TEXT 2", "REPLACE THIS TEXT 3", "REPLACE THIS TEXT 4",  "REPLACE THIS TEXT 5"]
        var replace="<br />";
        var replace2 =/[\r\n]+/g;
        var replace3 = ["TEXT REPLACED 1","TEXT REPLACED 2", "TEXT REPLACED 3","TEXT REPLACED 4","TEXT REPLACED 5"];
        for (i=0; i<mystring.length; i++){
            mystring = mystring.replace(find3[i], replace3[i]);
        }
        
        for (i=0; i<find1.length; i++){
          var regex = new RegExp(replace2,"g");
           mystring = mystring.replace(regex, "");
       }
        
        for (i=0; i<find1.length; i++){
          var regex = new RegExp(find1[i],"g");
           mystring = mystring.replace(regex, "");
       }
         mystring = mystring.replace(find2, replace);
    for (i=0; i< mystring.length; i++) {
    mystring = mystring.replace("<br /><br />", "<br />");
    }
   
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=mystring;
        console.log(mystring);
        } 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Clear text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="columns mt-0 pt-0 mb-5 is-mobile">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column is-three-quarters mb3">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Enter text here:</label>
    <div class="control">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Text" id="myTextArea">Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 1
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text for DELETE 1
2024
Text for DELETE 2
2024
Text for DELETE 4
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text for DELETE 5
DEER
2024
Text for DELETE 6
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 2
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 3
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
REPLACE THIS TEXT 4
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
DEER
Text Value 
Text Value
ELK
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
ELK
2024
Text Value 
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
Text Value 
PANDA
2024
Text for DELETE 7
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text Value 
DEER
2024
PANDA
2024
Text Value 
THUNDERBIRD
2024
Text for DELETE 9
PANDA
2024
Text for DELETE 10
2024</textarea><Br>
       <button class="button is-link" onclick="textareadValue();">Clean</button>
    </div>
  </div><br clear="all">
   <div id="result" class="pl-10"></div>
 </div>
<div class="column"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>




If you add then to the DOM, you can (reverse) loop over the children, and remove any duplicate element.
Might want to extend this to capture the first/last one.

The below results in
<br>
<em>Hello!</em>

<br>
<em>Hello!</em>

<br>
<em>Hello!</em>

<br>
<em>Hello!</em>

<br>
<em>Hello!</em>

<br>




const cs = document.body.children;
for (let i = cs.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    current = cs[i];
    before = cs[i - 1];
    if (current.nodeName === before.nodeName) {
        current.remove();
        console.log(`Removing child #${i}:`, current)
    }
}
<br />
<em>Hello!</em>

<br />
<em>Hello!</em>

<br />


<br />
<em>Hello!</em>

<br />
<em>Hello!</em>

<br />


<br />
<em>Hello!</em>

<br />


<br />

<br />




"add them to the DOM" - as a next step/extension to this, it should be possible without adding to the DOM.  See this answer or, if [tag:jquery] available, a simple $("<div/>").html(str) to work on it in memory.

@0stone0 but did I really have DOM case here? I store text for replacement in mystring variable and show it in block document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=mystring;

The comment above mentions a solution to that. But setting innetHTML to dom strings is not really a good way of populating the DOM. Perhaps you can add a [mre] to your question?

@0stone0 inserted full example in the question text.
